# Regular Expressions find and replace

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am having problems with RegEx in PHP and can't seem to find the answer.

I have a string, which is 3 letters, all caps ie COS.

the letters will change but always be 3 chars long and in caps, it will also be in the center of another string, surrounded by commas.

I need a regEx to find 3 caps letter inside a string and cahnge them from COS to 'COS'
(im doing this to amend a sql insert string)

I can't seem to find the regEx unless i use spercifit letter but the letters will change.

I need something along the lines of
[A-z]{3} then replace with '[A-Z]' (I know this isnt anywere near correct, just shorthand)

Anyone any suggestions?

Cheers

EDIT:

Just wanted to add incase anyone comes accross this question at a later date:

the sql insert string (provided from an external source and ftp's to my server daily)
contained the 3 capital string twice, once with commas and once with out
so I had to also remove the double commas added from the first regEx

`$sqlString = preg_replace('/([A-Z]{3})/', "'$1'", $isqlString);
$sqlString = preg_replace('/\'\'([A-Z]{3})\'\'/', "'$1'", $sqlStringt);`

Thanks everyone

Comment: You should rather fix the function that generates the SQL string in the first place.

Comment: yes youve solved it perfectly, thanks. Iv selected you answer as the correct one. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were actually very close. You could use:

```
echo preg_replace('/([A-Z]{3})/', "'$1'", 'COS'); //will output 'COS'
```

For MySQL statements I would advise to use the function `mysql_real_escape_string()` though.

Comment: it depends on what else is in the string too - if you know these 3 uppercase chars are inside commas  (as in no spaces ',COS,') then you can further limit the replacement like so: preg_replace('/,([A-Z]{3}),/', ",'$1',");

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = preg_replace('/([A-Z]{3})/', "'$1'", $string);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's like you said, "three capital letters surrounded by commas, e.g.

> Foo bar,COS,Foo Bar

You can use look-ahead and look-behinds and find the letters:

```
(?<=,)([A-Z]{3})(?=,)
```

Then a simple replace to surround with single quotes will be adequate:

```
'$1'
```

All together, [Here's it working](http://www.ideone.com/HMU5F).

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/(^|\b)([A-Z]{3})(\b|$)/', "'${2}'", $string);
```

Comment: You do need to specify word boundary otherwise "ABC,COSTARICA,XYZ" will have more than 3 replacements you intended. Look at http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php for more details.